# AppKit framework and NSEvent.h in Cocoa Touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, frameworks, import, nsevent

I want to write a method that needs NSEvent defined, so I need NSEvent.h. The SDK I am using (3.1.3) doesn't seem to have NSEvent.h within its frameworks.  I found that it is in AppKit.framework, which I have under /Developers.  Using Xcode, I navigated to the location of this AppKit and added it.  Now AppKit appears in Xcode along with UIKit and so on in the Frameworks list, and when I open the AppKit framework's Headers in Xcode, it lists AppKit.h and NSEvent.h.  Nonetheless, the lines:

```
 #import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
 #import <AppKit/NSEvent.h>
```

both produce "no such file or directory" messages.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppKit and NSEvent are not part of the iOS SDK. That is, they can't be used on the iPhone, iPod, or iPad. Only on the Mac.